# Dynamic Div Height Calculation - JQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I've written a small lightbox plugin for jQuery (yes, there are several ready made packages -- unfortunately, the designer in my co. does not like any of them).

I have one small problem -- I am using .load() to load dynamic flash content into the lightbox div. I am appending the div to the DOM, presetting visibility to hidden, and using .outerHeight(true) and .outerWidth(true) to get the dimensions. In internet explorer, I am getting a height of 61px (margin + 1px).

Assumption: contentContainer is already appended to the body dom frag

```
var remote = $(document.createElement("div"));
remote.css( "margin", "30px" );     
var loadURL = $(this).attr( 'href' );

if( typeof( isImage ) == "undefined" || !isImage ){
    console.log( "Loading " + loadURL );
    contentContainer.append( remote );
    remote.load( loadURL, function(){                   
        contentContainer.css( "left", (currWindow.width/2) - (contentContainer.outerWidth(true)/2) )
            .css( "top", document.body.scrollTop + (currWindow.height/2) - (contentContainer.outerHeight(true)/2) );
        overlay.css( "visibility", "visible" );
        contentContainer.css( "visibility", "visible" );
    });
}
```

A basic div with explicitly set height and width is what is being loaded into remote.

Any suggestions? I think its something stupid about when I'm trying to calculate the height and width. It worked with a basic image though...

Josh

Comment: IE8 actually.

Also after I posted, its worth mentioning that I'm trying to center the div on the screen absolutely. Works in FF natively and works in IE if i pop an alert first, wait half a second, then click okay (presumably the content from the ajax request is fully loaded, and thus IE can calculate the height). I'm just not sure where/when I should ask for the height if not in the load finish callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try surrounding the contents of the callback in a window.setTimeout with 0 milliseconds. This will wait for the current call stack to unwind before executing. In my experience, this fixes some IE issues with callback timing when the callback executes after the browser event fires, but before IE redraws the window.

Comment: This little trick has solved a few problems I've had with IE.